# React dynamic form input useRef typeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a React form with dynamic input fields that a user can add and remove input fields. I validate when i submit the form. If input is empty, input gets focused with useRef hook. The problem is that if i have two inputs empty, so i add a second input and remove it after, i am getting typeError "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')".

[image]

[image: Edit React Dynamic Form]

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([""]);

  const fieldRef = useRef();

  const fieldsIsValid =
    fields.length >= 1 && fields.every((field) => field.trim() !== "");

  function handleChange(i, event) {
    const values = [...fields];
    values[i] = event.target.value;
    setFields(values);
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    const values = [...fields];
    values.push("");
    setFields(values);
  }

  function handleRemove(i) {
    const values = [...fields];
    values.splice(i, 1);
    setFields(values);
  }

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!fieldsIsValid) {
      if (fields.length >= 1) {
        fieldRef.current.focus();
        return;
      }
      return;
    }
    console.log(fields);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleAdd()}>
          Add Input
        </button>
        {!fieldsIsValid && <p className="error">Input is required</p>}
        {fields.map((field, idx) => {
          return (
            <div key={`${"input"}-${idx}`}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter text"
                value={field || ""}
                ref={fieldRef}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
              />
              <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemove(idx)}>
                X
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button className="margin-top" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have to create multiple refs, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245376/react-useref-with-array-for-dynamic

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about multiple refs. I tried but i didn't solve it. I will try more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andreas already mentioned, you need to create multiple refs for multiple inputs. There is always one-to-one mapping/assignment of React refs to DOM nodes. If you use the same ref at multiple positions, the `ref` would be linked to the last node you have used it for. To help you understand this, check the error you are getting here. It says, "cannot read properties of `null`" i.e. the value of `fieldRef.current` is null since the DOM node fieldRef was last mapped with (the last input field) does not exist after deletion in the DOM tree.

You can try to implement the same functionality by instead putting the ref on the form tag and not the input tags, like so:

```
<form onSubmit={submitHandler} ref={fieldRef}>
```

```
function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    for (let elem of fieldRef.current.elements) {
      if (elem.type === 'text' && elem.dataset.required && !elem.value) {
        elem.focus()
        return
      }
    }
  }
```

```
<input
     type="text"
     data-required="true"    // <---- Add this here
     placeholder="Enter text"
     value={field || ""}
     onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
 />
```

Comment: Well, in reality i have a big form with many static inputs and two dynamic input fields. I only send a CodeSandBox with a part of my form where the problem appears . Will it work in a big form with many static inputs and two dynamic input fields? I mean if it is good practice putting the ref in the form tag etc.

Comment: Yes, it would work for a form having thousands of inputs enclosed. Don't worry. You can verify that yourself. :)

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the following doc, don't overuse refs. That's actually not a good practice. Just have a single ref on form and that will solve your problem. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

Comment: I tried it but in my case it doesn't work as i want. Because i have overused refs. i have a different ref for each input.

Comment: Don't use ref for each input. Just have one ref on the form tag and that will solve your problem. Check the code I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, i checked the code, but i have text inputs that can be empty, other text inputs that are required, a email input that must be valid email, a phone input that must be valid phone etc,. If i use a ref in form, text inputs that are not required are getting focused. I might remove all refs and change the submit button to enabled/disabled if form is valid.

Comment: Oh okay. To fix that, check the updated code with `data-required` attribute. :)

Comment: I think with data attribute will work, i will test it. Is it okay if i add the for loop inside the condition `if (!fieldsIsValid) {}`? Btw, i am using refs only for focus. Is this considered still overusing? Instead of using `data-required` attribute, can i use `elem.id`?