# Why I can't call useRef inside callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I write this code I have an error:

> React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

What should I do with this code?

```
return ITEMS.map((item, i) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
      return (
        <div
          ref={elementRef}
          key={i}
        >
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          <Wrapper>
            {item.name === visibleItem && (
                <Item
                  parentRef={elementRef}
                />
            )}
          </Wrapper>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Use `createRef` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use multiple refs for an array of elements with hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633690/how-can-i-use-multiple-refs-for-an-array-of-elements-with-hooks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possibilities, Either using `useRef` with an object/array, or using `createRef` as suggested by Yevgen Gorbunkov.

I'm not entirely sure as to the viability of these as the `createRef` option will create entirely new refs on each render, and the `useRef` option you'll need to make sure your keys/indexes are always the same.

```
const ITEMS = [{ name: "test" }, { name: "test2" }];
export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef({});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {ITEMS.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={idx} ref={element => (ref.current[idx] = element)}>
            <p>{item.name}</p>
            <Wrapper>
              {item.name === visibleItem && (
                <Item parentRef={ref.current[idx]} />
              )}
            </Wrapper>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {ITEMS.map((item, idx) => {
        const ref = createRef();
        return (
          <div key={idx} ref={ref}>
            <p>{item.name}</p>
            <Wrapper>
              {item.name === visibleItem && <Item parentRef={ref} />}
            </Wrapper>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```