# Accessing key property of React component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, react-component, react-leaflet

1. I map through an array of locations
2. I want to access the key of the component via onClick
3. This is my console.log`const addTo = (element) => {console.log(element);};`

```
return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => {

        return (
          <Marker key={Math.random()} position={item.fields.location}>
            <Popup>
              {item.fields.name} <br></br>
               <button
                onClick={() => {
                  addTo(item.fields.name);
                }}
              >Add 
              </button>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `key of the component`?

Comment: `key` is a special react prop. It won't be accessible as `props.key` in a component even if you passed it as a prop. But if you need it, you can pass it with a different name: `<MyComponent key={123} myKey={123} />` and access it as `props.myKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name:

Therefore you need to either store the key as a variable or pass it as another prop name

```js
return (
    <>
      {data.map((item, index) => {
        const key = index;
        return (
          <Marker key={key} position={item.fields.location}>
            <Popup>
              {item.fields.name} <br></br>
               <button
                onClick={() => {
                  addTo(item.fields.name);
                  console.log(key)
                }}
              >Add 
              </button>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

(Also you should consider using another `key` other than `Math.random`, as that changes with every render of the component)

If you want to access the element itself, you should consider using an attribute (i.e. `data-id={index}`) or better yet a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633947/1554860) explains how to create multiple `ref`s

Comment: This worked, thanks. I will use uuid instead of math random.