# Accessing any element in a useRef is throwing 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a ref in React, which is an array that contains references to multiple other divs in the DOM.

In a useEffect, I map through an object to render the divs, and I assign a ref to each div. Before assigning the ref, I instantiate a slot for it with `createRef`.

I'm essentially trying to replicate what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633947/2891356) answer has suggested doing.

The issue that I'm running into is that my compiler keeps seeing `undefined`. I'm not sure why this is happening, but here is the code that I have:

```
import React from "react";

const items = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
];
export default function Component() {
  const [renderedItems, setRenderedItems] = React.useState();
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);
  const refsArray = React.useRef([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const heightOfFirstDiv = refsArray.current[0].offsetHeight;
    console.log("heightOfFirstDiv", heightOfFirstDiv); // <-- this is always undefined
    setHeight(heightOfFirstDiv);
  }, [renderedItems]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setRenderedItems(
      items.map((item, index) => {
        refsArray.current[index] = React.createRef();

        return (
          <div
            ref={refsArray.current[index]}
            style={{ height: 100, width: 40 }}
          >
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      The height is: {height || "undefined"}
      {renderedItems}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: awesome-thompson-110v2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063129/14729626) to the question you have linked is better and simpler, actually. This can be implemented via [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs):

```
import React from "react";

const items = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
];
export default function Component() {
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);
  const refsArray = React.useRef([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const heightOfFirstDiv = refsArray.current[0].offsetHeight;
    console.log("heightOfFirstDiv", heightOfFirstDiv);
    setHeight(heightOfFirstDiv);
  }, [renderedItems]);

  const renderedItems = items.map((item, index) => (
    <div
      ref={(el) => (refsArray.current[index] = el)}
      key={index}
      style={{ height: 100, width: 40 }}
    >
      {item}
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      The height is: {height || "undefined"}
      {renderedItems}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Storing rendered elements in component state is not a good practice, as it makes components complicated, confusing and hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your current[0] is in fact an object with a .current key inside it, you can get the value you want by simply editing your heightOfFirstDiv to show that key

```
 const heightOfFirstDiv = refsArray.current[0].current.offsetHeight;
```

If you notice, on the example you tried to replicate you'll see they destructured this .current key, that's where the mistake came from