# How to set refs in a React map to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I have a container (parent) Component that, among other things, renders a bunch of child components via a `map`.  I need to create a `ref` in the Parent to the Child components.  I now know you can not apply refs directly to Components. Refs need to be applied to DOM/HTML elements.

Assume a setup like:

`ContainerComponent.js`

```
export default function ContainerComponent() {
    const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6] // this could be an array of anything
    return (
        {list.map(item => <Child data={item} />)
    )
}
```

`Child.js`

```
export default function Child({data}) {
    // this could be more complex
    return (
        <p>{data}<p>
    )
}
```

Is there a way to create an of refs like:

`const itemsRef = useRef(Array(list.length).fill(createRef()));`

Then pass a reference to `itemRef` to Child via prop. Then set itemRef.current to the ref of the p element, many in a `useEffect`

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633690/how-can-i-use-multiple-refs-for-an-array-of-elements-with-hooks

Comment: Thank you, but no.  that example shoes the map function returning dom elements directly.  In my example, the map function returns components

Comment: Then you might need to use `forwardRef` . https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html