# How can I get old value in input's onChange event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have some inputs defined in react. I'm assigning a function to their `onChange` function. I can find the current value. How can I get the old value in simplest way?

The reason I want this is because I want to find the ratio of this new value to the old value and do some operations.

Sample code:

```
let onChange = (e) => {
    let newValue = e.target.value; // let oldValue = will be here     

}

<Input type="number"  onChange={onChange }></Input>
```

Comment: You probably need `useRef` to store the old value and compare it with the current. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: I create the inputs dynamically and add the event to them at that time. It is unclear how many references there will be for this.

Comment: let [layerArr, setLayerArr] = React.useState([])

Comment: ``` {layerArr.map((layer, index) => {
                        return (<div key={index}>
                            <Label htmlFor={layer}>Layer - {index + 1}</Label>
                            <Input id={"layer-" + (index + 1)} type="number" className="layer" onChange={onChangeLayerHeight} defaultValue={defaultLayerValue}></Input>
                        </div>)
                    })}  ```

Comment: I mean the number of inputs changes dynamically. and accordingly the UI is updated again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the old value is not needed in the component state, use a ref like the following, you can change its initial value

```
const oldValueRef = React.useRef(0)

let onChange = (e) => {
    const oldValue = oldValueRef.current;
    let newValue = e.target.value; // let oldValue = will be here

    // after everything     
    oldValueRef.current = e.target.value;
}

<Input type="number" onChange={onChange }></Input>
```

Comment: i was able to do it by applying the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633690/how-can-i-use-multiple-refs-for-an-array-of-elements-with-hooks) thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use a state to do it:

```
const [state, setState] = useState("");

let onChange = (e) => {
  let oldValue = state; 
  let newValue = e.target.value;
  setState(newValue)
  // your logic
};

<Input type="number" value={state} onChange={onChange}></Input>;
```