# In react, how can I add multiple ref to the element using map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
export default function RenderPages({storage, setStorage, state, setState}){
const elRefs=[]
for(let i=0; i<storage[state.currentFolderId][state.currentFileId].content.length; i++){
    elRefs.push(useRef())
}

return (
    <>
    {
      renderable
      ?<div className="writing">
        {storage[state.currentFolderId][state.currentFileId].content.map((page, index)=>
        <div className='textarea'>
          <textarea ref={elRefs[index]} placeholder='write here' value={page} id={"page"+index} onChange={(e)=>onChange(e, index)} rows={rows} cols={cols}></textarea>
        </div>)}
      </div>
      : <></>
    }
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to attach multiple ref to random number of "textarea" element. the number of element would be determined by the variable, "storage", which is given as props. I got error with above code. Help me please.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Maybe possible duplication ? The answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633947/5618326.

Comment: This error. "React Hook "useRef" may be executed more than once. Possibly because it is called in a loop. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use `for` loop to push the elements in ref, you already use `map` in `return` you can push `textarea` elements using ref like this way as you can see the below code, I hope this works. thanks

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function RenderPages({storage, setStorage, state, setState}) {
  const elRefs = useRef([]);

  return (
    <>
      {renderable ? (
        <div className="writing">
          {storage[state.currentFolderId][state.currentFileId].content.map((page, index) => (
            <div className="textarea">
              <textarea
                ref={ref => {
                  elRefs.current[index] = ref
                }}
                placeholder="write here"
                value={page}
                id={'page' + index}
                onChange={e => onChange(e, index)}
                rows={rows}
                cols={cols}></textarea>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myRefs = useRef([])
ref={ref => myRefs.current[index] = ref} // <--- Right syntax
```

- Using one ref with multiple current elements is enough
- Shouldn't (and don't need) call hook in a loop, in this case, it's invalid https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level