# Why does only one of my videos play on hover with UseRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I have a row of thumbnails that are supposed to play a video when I hover over them, and stop when I mouse out of the thumbnail. As of right now, only the last thumbnail plays it's video when I hover, all the other ones are frozen. But if I hover over one of the frozen videos, then back to the working video, the working video will have moved forward as if I was hovering over it the whole time.

This is my component

```
import React from 'react'
import { projectlist } from '../../projectlist'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import './Projects.css'

export default function Projects() {
  const playerRef = useRef<any>()

  function onMouseOver(){
    console.log('playerRef',playerRef)
    playerRef.current.play();
  }

  function onMouseOut(){
    playerRef.current.pause();
  }

  return (
    <div className='projects-container'>

      {projectlist.map((video)=>{
        return(
          <div className='project-image' key={video.video_id} onMouseOver={onMouseOver} onMouseOut={onMouseOut}>
            <video ref={playerRef} muted loop>
              <source src={video.test} type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
            <img src={video.image}/>
          </div>
        )
      })}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the CSS incase it is relevant

```
.project-image{
    position: relative;

    img{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    video{
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    &:hover{
        video{
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I used this video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIX0DSaNOjI&ab_channel=ColbyFayock around the 15:30 mark is where I followed the useRef guide.

Comment: You need multiple ref for elements check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633690/how-can-i-use-multiple-refs-for-an-array-of-elements-with-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple. You have only one `ref` and multiple videos. How can the system or anyone identify which video the ref is for. Also, all your videos have only one listener for `mouseOut` and `mouseOver` each.

You need a list of `ref`s, one for each video. Or you need a ref, which can hold multiple values.

Now, you also have to modify your functions to ensure that there is an identifier for each video.

```
export default function Projects() {
  const playerRef = useRef<any>(new Array(projectlist.length).fill(false));

  function onMouseOver(index){
    console.log('playerRef',playerRef)
    playerRef.current[index].play();
  }

  function onMouseOut(){
    playerRef.current[index].pause(index);
  }

  return (
    <div className='projects-container'>

      {projectlist.map((video,index)=>{
        return(
          <div className='project-image' key={video.video_id} onMouseOver={() => { onMouseOver(index) }} onMouseOut={() => { onMouseOut(index) }}>
            <video ref={playerRef} muted loop>
              <source src={video.test} type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
            <img src={video.image}/>
          </div>
        )
      })}

    </div>
  )
}
```

You can also follow the video and create a `ref` and `method` for each video seperately.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example for your reference:

```js
let pause = (e) => {
  let video = e.target;
  video.pause();
}
let start = (e) => {
  let video = e.target;
  video.play();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video muted loop onMouseOver={start} onMouseOut={pause}>
          <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"/>
      </video>
</div>
<div>
  <video muted loop onMouseOver={start} onMouseOut={pause}>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4"/>
  </video>
</div>
```